# Export to csv using bulk copy, conversion error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

While trying to export a SQL Server table to a `.csv` file using bulk copy, the following errors occur:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.
>
> Unable to resolve column level collations

Copying starts and then an error is thrown.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Now I get this as an output...

[image]

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @raw_sql VARCHAR(8000);



SET @table_name ='clients'

SELECT @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader + ',', '') + QUOTENAME('name', 
'''')
FROM    [dbo].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE   C.TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name
select @raw_sql = 'bcp "select '+ @columnHeader +' name, 
uniqClientID,registrationNumber,
                                name,vatNumber, CAST(legalEntity AS 
varchar(10)) AS legalEntity from [dbo]..Clients" ' +' queryout 
C:\ClientsHeaderF.csv -c -t -T -S' + @@servername
EXEC  xp_cmdshell @raw_sql
```

Comment: Your column headers are all strings and your columns values are probably not all strings. You need to replace `SELECT *` with a column list and ensure that all non string columns are explicitly converted to string.

Comment: To debug these errors it helps to ensure that your underlying source SQL query is valid. It can be easily validated by executing it on its own.

Comment: Alex, when I declare all column names in my query and cast all non varchar types to varchar I receive this...
output
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]

Comment: Isolated query executes just fine

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that you executed in isolation. Note: I am looking for a similar dynamic SQL code (with column header query etc.) to what you currently have minus the `bcp` parts. Once you get this version working, simply add `bcp` parts to it to get the final result.

Comment: Debugging rule number 2: when you change something and you receive a different error it does not mean that what you did is totally wrong and that you should go back, maybe you just did not make enough changes to get it right.

Comment: On StackOverflow, people prefer code as formatted text, not images. It is easier to copy paste it to test with, rather than typing it all ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the code as text. In your edited code you still use `'name'` as a literal string. This will still result in a comma separated string with  the word 'name' multiple times. You should use `COLUMN_NAME` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS `.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.
I get the same output when I replace literal with COLUMN_NAME.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the value of `@raw_sql` as well as the query you executed (the one which you said "executes just fine")?

Comment: Can you take a look at my last comment, I managed to output headers, but there is no any data.

Answer (score -1):

This is too long for a comment:

I guess I understand what you are trying to do with

```
SELECT @ColumnHeader = COALESCE(@ColumnHeader, ',', '') + '''' + 'name' + ''''
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE   C.TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name
```

But have you actually tried it?

The resulting `@ColumnHeader` looks something like:
`,'name''name''name''name'`.

You say "Isolated query executes just fine". I doubt that.

I think you mean to use:

```
SELECT @ColumnHeader = COALESCE(@ColumnHeader + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME, '''')
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE   C.TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name
```

Comment: I receive null as an output, when I execute a procedure.

Comment: @T.Dejan I am not sure what I'm supposed to do with that comment. I've edited the 'answer' to include a corrected version.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I have attempted to explain to OP how to debug and solve the problem on his own. I get the feeling that this is not the expected help. The expectation is to receive a fully working code dump.

Comment: Expectation is to solve this somehow, I tried your approach and edited my answer to indicate the output I get.